# How do you create a 1-column, 2-row flex-box layout?

Tags: css, flexbox

#### Given the following markup:

```
<div class="box">
  <div class="A">A</div>
  <div class="B">B</div>
  <div class="C">C</div>
</div>
```

#### How do I achieve the following layout:

[image]

#### With the following behavior:

- **A** has fixed width of 150px
- Height of **C** is based on the height of the content inside of it (which changes), but it always remains fixed to the bottom.
- The flex container (**.box**) width takes up the full width of the browser.
- **B** and **C** always take up the remaining width of the container (**.box**) after **A**'s 150px of width is taken into account.

> What about A's and B's height? Is it fixed or it varies depending on
>   the content or something else?

The height of the content inside of **A** will not change, but the height of the content inside of **B** will change. **.box** height should equal max(height **A**, height **B** + **C**)

**[Here's a pen where everything is stubbed out](http://codepen.io/gilbox/pen/rLFHh)**

Comment: What about A's and B's height? Is it fixed or it varies depending on the content or something else?

Comment: absolute ? http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/egBAK or  extra markup http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/xtjhD ?

Comment: Thank you @GCyrillus, your second solution satisfies the conditions except for the nested flex boxes which is only a concern in regards to browser compatibility.

Comment: @oneday I clarified in the question

Answer (score 10):

Your result is conceptually simple, but you need to use more than just 3 consecutive elements to accomplish what you want. Flex box is the bee's knees but it can't magic your layout. You need a separate sub-layout.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
.a, .b, .c {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.box {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}
.flex {
  display: flex;
}
.a {
  flex: 0 0 150px;
}
.b-c {
  flex-direction: column;
  display: flex;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
.b {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="box flex">
  <div class="a">A</div>
  <div class="b-c flex">
    <div class="b">B</div>
    <div class="c">C</div>
  </div>
</div>
```